# psql (postresql) \i: Отказано в доступе

Tags: postgresql, psql

Не получается импортировать sql файл в созданную ранее БД. В psql вход уже осуществлен. Команда импорта:

```
postgres=# \i /home/mb/myfirstproject/employee.sql
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
/home/mb/employee.sql: Отказано в доступе
```

Права на чтение и запись менял (`sudo chmod 755 /путь/к/файлу`). Файл пробовал кидать в разные папки (сейчас он лежит /home/mb/myfirstproject/). В PGadmin через Restore тоже не получилось: пишет ошибку в Process Watcher: pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Есть идеи как можно решить проблему? Уже несколько часов гуглю, пробую, но бестолку.

Comment: chmod 777 myfile

Comment: что говорит команда `file /home/mb/employee.sql`?
_pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive_
значит указанный вами для pg_restore  файл не является дампом в допустимом формате. в частности, pg_restore не умеет работать с дампами в формате SQL-команд. а вообще я бы на вашем месте использовал команду `show data_directory;`, чтобы узнать каталог кластера БД, и положил файл для импорта туда.